# When was extra time introduced in European football competitions?

Tags: football, history

All I know is that until 1965, a decider was required if 2 teams remained draw after the home and away matches.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

As by Fillet's comment:
There were 2 matches in the [67-68 Cup winners cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1967%E2%80%9368_European_Cup_Winners%27_Cup) quarter finals that went first to Extra Time, then to replay according to Wikipedia.

<strike>The first occurrence I came across was a second round Europa Cup I game in [73-74](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973%E2%80%9374_European_Cup) between CSKA Sofia and Ajax, that was decided in ET. *Going to check other cups too*</strike>

**Some background**
Extra Time after a tie did co-exist with a replay.

It seems, for UEFA competitions, that it first occurred in the 1957/58 [Europacup I final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_European_Cup_Final) between Real Madrid and AC Milan. But that was a one-legged match.

It only applied to the final. In previous rounds (double-legged) a third game was played.

In [1969/70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1969%E2%80%9370_European_Cup) the third game was abandoned and replaced by away goals and a toss if still tied. But away goals only applied for first two rounds (which was already in place for the third game).

In [1970/71](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970%E2%80%9371_European_Cup) the penalty shoot out was introduced in favor of the unfair coin toss. Away goals applied in all rounds.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the extra time was <strike>introduced in European football by fifa in 2004</strike>. Re-introduced by fifa in 2004

> LAW 7 - The Duration of the Match
>
> Extra Time  Competition rules may provide for two further equal
>   periods to be played.  The conditions of Law 8 will apply.

[The above is according to the FiFa history official website section](http://www.fifa.com/classicfootball/history/the-laws/2001-2006.html)

[interresting things you might want to know here too.](http://www.topendsports.com/sport/soccer/history.htm)

Even though I think this was a rule that got change with the implementation of sudden death and the golden goal around 1999. Which People complained about because of the amount of pressure on the length of the match that suddenly ended if a goal was scored. Hence in 2004 the extra time was restored.(well I think)

Comment: 2004 is not when it was introduced. You say it yourself: restored.